# Flutter / Dart Firestore response grab map item data from Array without iterating the entire thing?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

In a firestore document I have an Array that holds a list of maps that have a valueId that is either true or false:

[image]

I am able to see if a valueId exists in the array with `if(doc['inPack'].contains(valueID)){}`

But now that I know it exists in the array, is there an easy way to grab if the specific valueID is true or false without iterating through the entire array? Or will I have to run a loop to grab the value?

Just trying to see if there is a more efficient way of doing this, thanks!

Comment: Doesn't `doc['inPack']`give you a `List<Map<String, bool>>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your data structure, then you probably won't get the correct result using what you've presented...

You can use the `collection` package to get the `value` of the `key` if it exists in a Map that is somewhere in the array as the following:

```
// data is of type List<Map<String, bool>>

final value = data.firstWhereOrNull((e) => e.containsKey('key1'))?['key1'];
```

Check this dartpad for a quick demo:
https://dartpad.dev/f89e6ffa874295d9a7c7296db003c041

Comment: SO I think a map is the better direection here for me, instead of the array thanks. But now I am havign issues adding items to the map. I keep just overwritting the single item in the maps...

Comment: Post a separate question for that :)

Comment: I posted the new question here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73522154/how-to-add-or-edit-specific-value-within-a-map-on-a-firestore-document